# Oracle 11g Reports and Forms Properties Mass updates

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms, oraclereports

Brand new to dealing with Oracle Reports and Forms so forgive any terminology/syntax issues.

Given new assignment to help another developer put new systems into place.  New Systems are essentially COPIES of existing systems.

The process that I've seen involves a LOT of by hand updates of FORM properties (Names and Report Group Sources) and Same is true for REPORTS.  FRM and RDF files.
This is all done "by hand", open/change/save/next.

(Don't ask, it's one of those "we've always done this" and "we don't have time to look at a better way" kind of things.)

---

But in looking at this I thought surely there is a better way to handle this.
In my investigation I ran across several scripts that I think would be handy.  I could write a small app that pretty much automated this, but have a couple questions:

1.Would the following be the best process for handling forms?

--Copy forms file to XML process

```
for %%f IN (*.fmb) do frmf2xml OVERWRITE=YES %%f
```

--Do mass update of XML via some app Search/Replace

--Copy XML files back into FMB format

```
for %%f IN (*.xml) do frmxml2f OVERWRITE=YES USERID=<usr>/<pass>@<db> %%f
```

2. For Report Files looked like I had to alter RDF to be REX(?) files, then do the mass updates and reconvert?  For RDFs **I really don't synta**x but it would be something simliar to..

--Copy RDFs to REX

`for %%f IN (*.rdf) do rwconverter userid=scott/tiger@v817 batch=yes 
source=%%f ?????`

(Any help on syntax appreciated or links)

Or should the RDFs go to some other format? JSP?

--Do mass update of REX via some app Search/Replace

Then use rwConverter to copy REX files back to RDF?

---

Will converting to REX then back cause any issue for reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms mass update can be handled using JDAPI which is included with the forms builder install.A good starting point is in Forms Builder -> Help -> Online Help -> Contents -> Programming Oracle Forms with JDAPI.

Note: the following env variables need to be set correctly:

```
ORACLE_HOME={your forms/reports install}\{Oracle_FRHome1}
CLASSPATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\jlib\frmjdapi.jar;%CLASSPATH%
FORMS_PATH={path to your fmb's}
PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\jdk\bin;%PATH%
```

JDAPI works only on Forms, Menus and Libraries, does not work for Reports. I have used it to successfully modify a 400+forms application, changes included creating blocks, moving buttons, font change, window and canvas size change, removing deprecated fields.

Reports mass update, I have had limited success converting to xml then editing, the process worked on simple reports, on complex reports there were missing components when converting to XML then back to RDF (this may have been specific to our reports, you may have better results).