# Oracle Report RDF to REX versus RDF to XML

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I had asked a previous question on syntax of how to convert Oracle Reports of RDF format to REX, but never got an answer.

[Oracle 11g Reports and Forms Properties Mass updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37465186/oracle-11g-reports-and-forms-properties-mass-updates)

I got past that and actually converted to REX format. However I found that ONE of my REX files generated an error when I was using rwconverter to convert the type back from REX to RDF.  I could not get past it.

I switched to convert from RDF to XML, then from XML to RDF and that seems to work.  (I want to convert, do some batch editing, then put back in original format)

My question is....
Is there a different between converting RDF to REX and RDF to XML and back? 
Am I going to "lose" something in these conversions?